# Dynamic way to add length to an html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I'm looking for a way to update the video length on an HTML5 video in the client side using Javascript.

Example: I have a video clip loaded on the page that is 30 seconds long and I want to update it on the fly to be 45 seconds long.

I had a look at the duration property of the HTMLMediaElement, but quickly discovered that the property was read only (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). I also stumbled upon [this blog post](http://24ways.org/2012/html5-video-bumpers/), but my ideal solution would be to have one continuous clip. I could accomplish this on the server side using a tool like FFMPEG, but I'd rather not add an increase in load time for our users.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by that?

The song length is saved in the meta data for that song or that media file. When you download the song to that page its data is also downloaded. Which contains the song-title-name, and yes! length too.

To change that either you need to change the whole media or write the song length yourself. This is a link for the metadata change: http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/metadata.html. But this will change the metadata for the song while being uploaded, or being saved. It won't change it on the fly (As you want). **Again:** Use Ajax to use this code on the fly, just put the conversion code in a page, and access the page via ajax and write it to the page. Have a look at the following:

One approach for this would be, something like using jQuery ajax. You first update the metadata of the media using any code or language, then you send the media back to the page.

```
$.ajax({
url: "page_where_media_will_be_loaded",
data: "load_song_id=1234",
  success: function (result) {
    // write the song in some div as $("#idname").html(result);
  }
})
```

And then write it in the page. using the `.html()`. The **on the fly** thing has an option of ajax only. Ajax will communicate with server, load the new file, and update the current one!